# What is a Valid Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, calculation-puzzle

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Valid Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Valid Words™ | Not Valid Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SAFETY | DANGER |
| OFFICER | WORKER |
| TRAINING | TRAIN |
| SAUCEPAN | FRYPAN |
| ABANDONED | RENOUNCED |
| EXCELLENCE | PERFECTION |
| ASSORTMENT | VARIETY |
| MEANINGFUL | MEANINGLESS |
| COUNTERPOINT | BREAKPOINT |
| AZIDODEDIAZONIATIONS | HYDRODEDIAZONIATIONS |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Valid Words™,Not Valid Words™
SAFETY,DANGER
OFFICER,WORKER 
TRAINING,TRAIN 
SAUCEPAN,FRYPAN 
ABANDONED,RENOUNCED 
EXCELLENCE,PERFECTION 
ASSORTMENT,VARIETY 
MEANINGFUL,MEANINGLESS 
COUNTERPOINT,BREAKPOINT 
AZIDODEDIAZONIATIONS,HYDRODEDIAZONIATIONS
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Valid Word satisfies the rule

> If we convert each letter to a number ($A=1, B=2,\ldots, Z=26$) and add the values of all but the last letter then the result is congruent to the value of the last letter, modulo $26$. This is like a checksum for the word, similar to the Luhn algorithm used for credit cards as mentioned by FlanMan.

Examples

> $S+A+F+E+T = 19+1+6+5+20 = 51 \equiv 25 ($mod $26)$ and $Y=25$
>  $A+Z+I+D+O+D+E+D+I+A+Z+O+N+I+A+T+I+O+N = 1+26+9+4+15+4+5+4+9+1+26+15+14+9+1+20+9+15+14 = 201 \equiv 19(\mod 26)$ and $S=19$.

Comment: This answer is also valid too :D

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following, which failed, but it might give ideas for others to solve this.

After seeing Hint 1, I think the answer is:

> A Valid Word™ must somehow pass a credit card-style numerical validation using the Luhn algorithm: https://simplycalc.com/luhn-calculate.php. I converted some Valid Words™ into A1Z26 and to ASCII, but I could not find a way to get them all to pass the Luhn algorithm.